# Laravel passing 0 as value through form and getting null

Tags: php, laravel, forms, http-post

So I have a simple form with select input which has an option with value of "0" :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action('Something@something') }}">
    <select name="status">
           <option selected value="0">Bla bla bla</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Press me</button>
</form>
```

Error occurs, when I select the only option from select input and in controller I get null instead of "0" number (I did check with dd() method). Is it possible that this number gets lost in an integrated middleware or somewhere else? Or is this a PHP trick?

Comment: you are doing `dd($request->all())` and you are getting `null` for `status`?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I get "" instead of "0"

Comment: there is nothing by default that would be changing `0` to `null`/`''`, the only thing in place by default is the `TrimStrings` middleware which just trims strings

Comment: @lagbox Is there any other explanation why I get "" instead of "0"

Comment: I can pass like "-1", "1" and anything else but not "0"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer was that in my Middleware I had this code :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/blablabla');
    }

    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            $request->request->set($key, "");
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

problem was with `empty($value)`. I changed `empty()` to `!isset()` and everything fixed

Comment: why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: seems like you are trying to undo what `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware is doing

Comment: @lagbox It converts null to "" empty string. Probably found it out somewhere in the internet. Where do you find `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware? I can't seem to find it

Comment: it is added to the global middleware stack in Kernel.php, what version of Laravel are you using? and why do you want to explicitly convert the `null`s to empty strings?